# For a given integer $n>0$, can we efficiently determine whether an integer $y$ exist such that $n+y^2$ is a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, diophantine-approximation

I am trying to implement an efficient algorithm which must determine whether for a given integer $n>0$ another integer $y$ exist such that $n+y^2$ is a perfect square.

Based on some properties of $n$, can we make a statement about the existence of such a $y$ efficiently? Or reverse, is it possible for this $n$ to determine that there will be definitely no such $y$?

**What I found out so far:**

I found in the literature that a diophantine equation of the form:

$$x^2-Dy^2=n$$

is a so-called *"Norm-Form Equation"*. Hence in our case, we have the special case $D=1$.  However, as simple as the equation looks, it does not appear to be. For example [Richard A. Mollin](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Fundamental_Number_Theory_with_Applicati/Fsaa3MUUQYkC?gbpv=1&pg=PA294) involves in his Theorem 6.2.2 the divisor function which is not a very efficient operation:

[image]

It wold be great if there exist an efficient way to determine wheher for an positive integer $n$ exist another integer $y$ such that $n+y^2$ is a perfect square.

**Additional note:**
Even if the check routine generates some false positives in favor of efficiency, that would be absolutely ok. Being able to rule out that for a given natural $n$, no such $y$ exists would also be extremely helpful.

Comment: Given $n$, you want to know if there exists a $y$ and an $x$ such that $n + y^2 = x^2$, or what is the same thing, $n = x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$.  If $n$ is odd, the answer is always "yes": set $x = \frac{1}{2}(n+1)$ and $y = \frac{1}{2}(n-1)$.

Comment: If $n$ is divisible by $4$, the answer is always "yes": set $x = \frac{1}{4}(n+4)$ and $y = \frac{1}{4}(n-4)$.

Comment: How is checking whether $n$ has the remainder $2$ from division by $4$ "not very efficient"? Are you familiar with the [division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm)?

Comment: ...The answer is: check the last two digits of $n$. If it divides by four the remainder is two, there is no such $y$.

Comment: @EldarSultanow You forgot to mention that in our task we need ALL such `y` till some `limit`, not just single possible `y`. And also it would be worth to mention that most of times our `n` is also a square i.e. `n == m^2`, and we need to solve both tasks - at least to solve case when `n` is a square, and then also a general task when `n` is any integer.

Comment: Thank you all for these useful hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarizing the comments; your question can be rephrased as:

> Can we efficiently determine whether a given positive integer $n$ is of the form $n=x^2-y^2$, for some integer $x$ and $y$?

The answer is *yes*; a positive integer $n$ is of this form if and only if $n\not\equiv2\pmod{4}$. This has been asked here before, e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328195/x2-y2-n-has-solution-in-bbb-z-iff-n-not-equiv-2-pmod-4?noredirect=1).