# For a perfect square $n$, can we calculate integers $0<y<l$ up to a limit $l$ such that $n+y^2$ is a perfect square (without bruteforce)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, diophantine-approximation

I want to implement a fast algorithm (avoiding or at least minimizing bruteforce) which for a given square number $n$ calculates a series of positive integers $y$ up to a certain limit $l$ such that $n+y^2$ is again a perfect square?

I can obtain the trivial case $y=\frac{1}{2}(n-1)$ as described in the answer and comments on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4366995/for-a-given-integer-n0-can-we-efficiently-determine-whether-an-integer-y-e/) using the equation $(x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2$.

**Example:** Let us take $n=225(=15^2)$, we obtain one solution $y=\frac{1}{2}(225-1)=112$ directly. But how we can obtain the whole list $(8, 20, 36, 112)$?

**My ideas:** As described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4366995/for-a-given-integer-n0-can-we-efficiently-determine-whether-an-integer-y-e/) I came across the so called *"Norm-Form Equation"*, which is a diophantine equation of the form $x^2-Dy^2=n$ and we have the special case $D=1$. To deal with this Norm-Form Equation, in his [book](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Fundamental_Number_Theory_with_Applicati/Fsaa3MUUQYkC?gbpv=1&pg=PA294) Richard A. Mollin involves the divisor function.

Refering to our example, if we can deduce the other $y$-values $8,20,36$ from the (directly obtained) value $y=112$, it would allow me to speed up my bruteforce search drastically.

**Note:** If we cannot avoid bruteforce completely, I would be greateful for an approach that at least minimizes the search for these $y$-values.

Comment: If you have the divisors of $m$ it's easy to generate all the Pythagorean triples via the standard parameterization of the primitive triples: $$(u^2-v^2)^2+(2uv)^2=(u^2+v^2)^2$$

Comment: Good hint - thank you. So it requires us to factorize $n$ (which is not a very efficient operation, but which is doable).

Comment: This is called generalized Pell equation and there is an algorithm for finding all solutions, but it is complicated. [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html) gives references to Beiler and Dickson. Some solutions can be generated from a single one, but not all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the given problem, you neither need Pell-like equations nor Pythagorean triples. You just need , as mentioned , the divisors of $\ n\ $ :

You want the solutions of $$n+y^2=z^2$$ with positive integers $\ y\ $ and $\ z\ $

This means $$n=(z-y)(z+y)$$

Hence every pair of positive integers $a,b$ with $ab=n$ , where $a,b$ have the same parity gives a solution : $y=\frac{a-b}{2}$ , $z=\frac{a+b}{2}$

To ensure that $y$ is positive, $a$ must exceed $\sqrt{n}$

In PARI/GP, the following routine determines the pairs of positive integer solutions :

```
gp > n=225;fordiv(n,s,t=n/s;if(s^2>n,if(Mod(s,2)==Mod(t,2),[y,z]=[(s-t)/2,(s+t)/2];print(y," ",z))))
8 17
20 25
36 39
112 113
gp >
```

Comment: [Live version](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVxjEKgDAMRuGriFOKvxQCTiXewBNInYrQJUpTBHt661vep8K8hPMqKT-kMFRRbyGfZAevio7tSmRgJ_KrdmF_0aLsZHN1nkE2_Y_hLlkrvRiHEc31PnM6G8A=&lang=gp)

Comment: BTW, although it doesn't matter for correctness of mathematical explanation, original question had letter `n` instead of `m`. Also OP used `x` instead of your `z` in his Question. But corretness of Answer is alright without this.

Comment: I fixed the issue with "$m$" because I explicitely mentioned $\sqrt{n}$

Comment: @Peter: Thank you for this helpful algorithm. It speeds up searching routines. Arty: We just need to transfer Peter's PARI/GP Code into Python.

Comment: @EldarSultanow Please create Stack-Overflow Question with request for Python version. I already wrote a big Answer, with advanced Python code. But waiting for you to ask a Question. I did that answer and code few hours before Peter wrote his Answer. So my ideas and code is a bit different, but uses same common sub-idea that we just need to use Factorization as a fast way of finding all (X, Y) pairs.

Comment: [Python version](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyFUttqwzAMfc9XiMLATt11yegeCin7j9GHJHWYWX2pY1Par58U95KUlRkC8blIyZE6bzWoIH2wdt-D0s76AK2NJghov2tlBDhvd7ENWUfaLpp2ovUSSZlI66Svg_VXTsd9lu1kB66r0eV7pvk6Azw2BqjgaztcOnQ4UCY1ZKwU8M4FsDgwamDoi9hKwAcfwEggUwLUvOT8UpSOwma5gw3oO0an8bL-Gas0vGDTqoK3qVDDclmBm2AHeEScPUrf0y8UGNB2wh2_1V4-rf-sR-qT_wWnZq-1c9Ls2IFPBJjklUm6RA9_uIHi3nwkpI_W2yT0MkRviM2yT2VwFXBUw9CC7APTVVmuLvlS8IGCv2wEy0dzHc2gwVzSWjDcAAG4SgUfZ99Ajs-mehxSa01QJsobWGMlCguasZ3VsICGY8AlBVz8U-Qs4IR10DUnF1bDBbvWoNtN6TwGwGoBjYDZYjNDoyD7bI2vGu2nnID8zH8BSO7LOQ==&lang=python)

Comment: @PM2Ring Nice and simple Python version, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We begin with a formula that will generate
$\space (n,y,z):(n+y^2=z^2\space$ given two parameters which can be found given any number in the triple.

$$ n=(m^2-k^2)^2\qquad y=2mk\qquad z=m^2+k^2$$
We solve the $\space n$-function for $\space k,\space$ in terms of $\space m \space$ and $\space n.\quad$ Then we test a defined range of $\space m$-values and, any that yield an integer $\space k\space$ indicate the $\space (m,k)\space$ values needed to generate a triple.

$$n=(m^2-k^2)^2\implies k=\sqrt{m^2-\sqrt{n}}\\
\text{for}\qquad  \sqrt{\sqrt{n}+1} 
\le m \le 
\frac{\sqrt{n}+1}{2}$$
The lower limit ensures $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and the upper limit ensures $m> k$.
$$n=15^2\implies \sqrt{15+1}=4\le m \le \frac{15+1}{2} =8\\\text{and we find}\quad m\in\{4,8\}\implies k \in\{1,7\} $$
$$F(4,1)=(225,8,17)\qquad F(8,7)=(225,112,113) $$
But what about the other two  $\space y$-values? We find a triple for each of the prime factors of
$\space \sqrt{n}\space$ and then multiply the results by the cofactor(s). $\quad 225=3^2\times5^2\space$ so
$$n=3^2\implies \sqrt{3+1}=2\le m \le \frac{3+1}{2} =2\\
\text{and we find}\quad m\in\{2\}\implies k \in\{1\} $$
$$F(2,1)=(3^2,4,5)\longrightarrow 5^2(3^2,4,5)=(225,20,25) $$

$$n=5^2\implies \sqrt{5+1}=3\le m \le \frac{5+1}{2} =3\\
\text{and we find}\quad m\in\{3\}\implies k \in\{2\} $$
$$F(3,2)=(5^2,12,13)\longrightarrow 
3^2(5^2,12,13)=(225,36,39) $$

Comment: Great approach - will try this too!

Comment: @poetasis Maybe you can provide also a PseudoCode in any language (even english + math), a function that is given `n` and limit `l`, produces all integer solutions `(x, y)` of equation `n + y^2 = x^2`. This is exactly what is needed for our project. We will convert your PseudoCode to Python or C++ in our project. Also your formulas work only if factorization of `n` is known, or they can work even without factorization?

Comment: @Arty I hope my second answer is useful to you. The limit (l) is computed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Suggested code too big for a comment

Here is a test run of the code that follows it.

```
 Enter squared number n to find Y,Z.
 ? (3*5*7)^2
 Start time     09:06:11
 Input was 11025 
 F(2 , 1 )=(9 , 4 , 5 ) f2 = 35 ––> (11025 , 140 , 175 )
 
 F(3 , 2 )=(25 , 12 , 13 ) f2 = 21 ––> (11025 , 252 , 273 )
 
 F(4 , 3 )=(49 , 24 , 25 ) f2 = 15 ––> (11025 , 360 , 375 )
 
 F(4 , 1 )=(225 , 8 , 17 ) f2 = 7 ––> (11025 , 56 , 119 )
 F(8 , 7 )=(225 , 112 , 113 ) f2 = 7 ––> (11025 , 784 , 791 )
 
 F(5 , 2 )=(441 , 20 , 29 ) f2 = 5 ––> (11025 , 100 , 145 )
 F(11 , 10 )=(441 , 220 , 221 ) f2 = 5 ––> (11025 , 1100 , 1105 )
 
 F(6 , 1 )=(1225 , 12 , 37 ) f2 = 3 ––> (11025 , 36 , 111 )
 F(18 , 17 )=(1225 , 612 , 613 ) f2 = 3 ––> (11025 , 1836 , 1839 )
 
 F(11 , 4 )=(11025 , 88 , 137 ) f2 = 1 
 F(13 , 8 )=(11025 , 208 , 233 ) f2 = 1 
 F(19 , 16 )=(11025 , 608 , 617 ) f2 = 1 
 F(53 , 52 )=(11025 , 5512 , 5513 ) f2 = 1 
 Stop time  09:06:11
```

This is written in BASIC because it is easier than Python and available anywhere. Note: For those who don't speak BASIC, a colon (:) permits another command on the same line, a comma (,) prints a tab character, and a semicolon (;) does not print a carriage return so the next print statement will continue on the same line.

Note: $\space f1\space $ and $\space f2\space $
are the cofactors of $\space \sqrt{n}.$

```
 110 print : print
 120 print "Enter squared number n to find Y,Z."
 130 input n1
 140 print "Start time ",time$
 150 print "Input was " n1
 160 x1 = sqr(n1)
 170 if x1 = int(x1)
 180   for f1 = 1 to x1
 190     f2 = x1/f1
 200     if f2 = int(f2)
 210       gosub 290
 220     endif
 230   next f1
 240   print "Stop time ",time$
 250   end
 260 else 
 270   print "The number " n1 "is not a square.  "
 280   goto 120
 290 print
 300   v1 = int(sqr(f1+1)) : v9 = int((f1+2)/2)
 310   for m1 = v1 to v9
 320     if m1 > 1
 330       k1 = sqr(m1^2-f1)
 340       if k1 = int(k1)
 350         y1 = 2*m1*k1
 360         z1 = m1^2+k1^2
 370         print "F(" m1 ", " k1 ")=(";
 380         print f1^2 ", " y1 ", " z1 ") f2 = " f2;
 390 if f2 > 1
 400   print "––> ";
 410   print "(" f1^2*f2^2 ", " y1*f2 ", " z1*f2 ")"
 420 else 
 430   print
 440 endif
 450       endif
 460     endif
 470   next m1
 480 return
```

Comment: Amazing - Thanks! With Arty we will try to convert this ino python try this out. By the way we figured out some interesting behavior: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4386006/why-do-we-have-these-occurrences-of-primes-of-the-form-4k1-in-square-differen

Comment: Thanks for great code! Up-Voted. Reading it to understand and convert to our C++ project.