# Why do we have these occurrences of primes of the form $4k+1$ in square differences (Mengoli's Six-Square Problem)?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

For the present investigation Poetasis gave me the necessary impetus in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4384616/993738) on my related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384319/let-wx-be-integers-with-x2-w2-beeing-a-square-which-condition-they-must). I analyzed a large dataset of triples $w,x,y$ which fulfill the following diophantine system of equations:

$$x^2-w^2= \square_1\qquad y^2-x^2= \square_2\qquad y^2-w^2= \square_3$$

For this I included also very large triples such as $(w,x,y)=(11689849600,62507610880,64825529600)$ or $(w,x,y)=(17179869168,48806446500,49940015580)$.

I observed the following behavior to be very reliable/robust:

- The number of prime factors of the form $4k+1$ that $w$ contains range between $0$ and $8$
- The number of prime factors of the form $4k+1$ that $x$ contains range between $1$ and $8$
- The number of prime factors of the form $4k+1$ that $y$ contains range between $2$ and $8$

Hence $x$ must contain at least $1$, $y$ must contain at least $2$ of such prime factors and in every case the number of such prime factors (contained in $w,x,y$) cannot exceed $8$. Whether this observed upper limit of 8 really applies in general, I am not sure - even though I have really examined many such triples. To make it a little more vivid, here is my observation summarized in a table (I have included all triples containing integers up to a size of 12 million and then a few extra large triples up to almost $2^{36}$):

\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
& \text{occurrences in }w & \text{occurrences in }x & \text{occurrences in }y \\ \hline
0 & 33051 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 91340 & 12396 & 0 \\ \hline
2 & 92632 & 82493 & 40292 \\ \hline
3 & 52476 & 116551 & 107706 \\ \hline
4 & 19985 & 63612 & 98890 \\ \hline
5 & 4259 & 16554 & 38642 \\ \hline
6 & 576 & 2500 & 7810 \\ \hline
7 & 56 & 257 & 952 \\ \hline
8 & 5 & 17 & 88 \\ \hline
\end{array}

***My Question:***
Can we explain this?

And as a follow-up question, it would be intersting to know: Assuming we consider corresponding quadruples $(w,x,y,z)$ instead of these triples $(w,x,y)$, would $z$ have to contain $3$ such primes (of the form $4k+1$) as a factor or would the rules be much stricter for all integers $w,x,y,z$?

**Update:**
According the hint of Gerry Myerson we can conclude that $x$ must contain at least one prime factor of the form $4k+1$, since $x$ is a sum of two squares. A proof for this is, for example, given in *"Proofs from the book (Fifth edition)"* by Aigner and Ziegler (p. 21, chapter *"Representing numbers as sums of two squares"*), where he shows that every prime of the form $4k+1$ is a sum of two squares. Another reference is [Fermat's 4n+1 Theorem (Wolfram MathWorld)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fermats4nPlus1Theorem.html). Consequently, as mentioned by Gerry Myerson, $y$ must be divisible by at least two $4k+1$ primes, since $y$ is a sum of squares in two different ways. Continuing this idea for a quadruple $(w,x,y,z)$, $z$ must contain three distinct prime factors of the form $4k+1$, since $z$ is a sum of squares in three different ways.

Comment: If you multiply $x,y,w$ by any number $c$, you get another solution, so there's no bound to the number of factors that are primes of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: $x$ is a sum of two squares, so it must be divisible by at least one $4k+1$ prime. $y$ is a sum of squares in two different ways, so it must be divisible by at least two $4k+1$ primes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So there is no upper-bound. But what about lower bound? Does it exist? As we can see in the OP's experiment W has lower bound of 2 prime factors of form "4k + 1", Y has lower bound of 1 prime factor of this form.

Comment: Someone else asked about four squares with all pairwise differences square just a few days ago. Why is this topic suddenly popular?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Me and OP are implementing a special project (in Python and C++ languages) that has an aim of finding such 4-tuple `(w^2, x^2, y^2, z^2)` that has all 6 differences also being squares. After scanning all numbers below `2^34` we didn't find any such 4-tuple. But we found very many 3-tuples `(w^2, x^2, y^2)` of same property that all 3 differences between them are also squares. In order to scan much higher space of numbers much larger than current 2^34 we need very fast way of generating 3-tuples.So we're looking how to speedup current code.`4k + 1` task may give us good pre-filter

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Your hint is essential. I udated my post. I am still a bit surprised that I did not find a case beyond the upper limit of $8$ factors in my data set, but it is possible to construct such a case. Thank you first of all for your valuable advice.

Comment: I don't know if this helps but half of all triples have $\space w>x\space$ and half have $\space w<x.\quad$ Also

$d=|B-A|$ can be any prime number $(p)$ where $p\equiv\pm1\mod 8$ with (p) raised to any non-negative power. Under $100$,  $d\in \{1,7, 17, 23, 31, 41, 47, 49, 71, 73, 79, 89, 97\}$.

Comment: I can't find that earlier post on four squares with all pairwise differences square. It may have been deleted, which is a shame. It's my recollection that I gave a reference to Richard Guy's book, Unsolved Problems In Number Theory, 3rd Ed., in which there is some discussion of the problem, and I wish I could link back to that question/comment.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: All is well - nothing was deleted. We have the article - you surely mean [this one about the connection to solid geometries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4375353/how-we-may-express-four-squares-whose-difference-is-each-a-square-in-terms-of-p). And I organized also the book you recommended. There is on page 279 a graph displaying three cycles of five generator pairs.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Do you think we have a chance to describe this problem in terms of a four-rectangular 4D-polyhedron? That would be really interesting.

Comment: OK, thanks. I don't know why I couldn't find it. Doesn't one of the answers to the earlier problem relate it to a four-dimensional analogue of a cuboid?

Comment: Correct - that one answer gives a connection to a four-dimensional Cuboid/Euler Brick (that has six bounding faces in 3D, six bounding solids in 4D). It would be interesting to know whether we could manage this using an object bounded by 4 surfaces/bodies (like a trirectangular Pythagorean tetrahedron). I'll think about it and if I have something substantial, I can make a new post.