# When are $a+b$ and $ab$ palindromic for integers $a,b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, palindrome

This question came up when I was discussing Ex 1.23 of *An Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* (Apostol) with a user.

> For positive integers $a,b$, when are the values of $a+b$ and $ab$ palindromic?

A simple example to demonstrate this is when $a=3$ and $b=24$. The integers $27$ and $72$ are palindromic. Moreover, the pair $(2,2)$ is trivial.

Is it possible to find all the solutions $(a,b)$?

> **UPDATE:** The case $a=2$ has now been proven by myself and @Holo. The only solutions are indeed $(2, 5\cdot10^k-3)$ for a non-negative integer $k$. The case $a=3$ has also been shown that the only solution is $(3,24)$.

---

The following is a technical way to approach it for the general case.

*In general, if $a+b=c_{m-1}c_{m-2}\cdots c_1c_0$ has $m$ digits and $ab=c_0c_1\cdots c_{m-2}c_{m-1}$ has $n$ digits then $$a+b=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}10^ic_i\quad\text{and}\quad ab=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}10^ic_{m-i-1}$$ so we wish to solve the quadratic $$a^2-a\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}10^ic_i+\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}10^ic_{m-i-1}=0$$ or $$2a=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}10^ic_i\pm\sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}10^ic_i\right)^2-4\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}10^ic_{m-i-1}}.$$ What is important about this is that we want $$\left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}10^ic_i\right)^2-4\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}10^ic_{m-i-1}=k^2\implies \left(\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}10^ic_i\right)^2-k^2=4\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}10^ic_{m-i-1}$$ for some integer $k$, which kind of resembles [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/multiples-of-4-as-sum-or-difference-of-2-squares).*

Comment: Note that if $a$ and $b$ both have three or more digits, then $ab$ has more digits than $a+b$, ruling out palindromosity.

Comment: My point being, this greatly reduces the space of possible examples. One can surely go farther, and rule out, say, $a$ having two digits, and $b$ having four or more. One may get it to the point where one can go through all the possibilities by hand, and solve the problem.

Comment: Some initial observations: Assume WLOG $a \le b$.  Then any example has $a \le 20$.  If $a > 20$ then we have $ab/(a+b) > 20b/(a+b) \ge 20b/2b > 10$.  (The first inequality follows from $a > 20$ and the second from $a \le b$.)     This suggests case analysis based on the value of $a$.  We also can't have $a = 10$ or $a = 20$ because then $ab$ would end in $0$. Since $ab$ and $a + b$ have the same digits they are congruent mod 9.  Enumerating the possible values of $a$ and $b$ mod 9 gives that $(a,b)$, reduced mod 9, is one of $(0, 0), (2, 2), (3, 6), (6, 3), (8, 5), (5, 8)$.

Comment: Searching exhaustively with $a \le 20, b \le 100000$ finds $(a, b) = (2, 2), (2, 47), (2, 497), (2,4997), (2, 49997), (3, 24), (9, 9)$ and no other solutions.  I conjecture that the solutions are $(a, b) = (2, 5 \times 10^k - 3)$ for all nonnegative integers $k$ and the sporadic solutions $(3, 24)$ and $(9, 9)$.  This assumes that something like $(5, 26)$ doesn't count, i. e. $31$ is not the reversal of $130$.

Comment: At https://www.quora.com/What-are-numbers-whose-sum-is-reverse-of-their-product there's a claim – without any proof – that $(2,2)$, $(2,47)$, $(3,24)$, and $(9,9)$ are the only solutions (but obviously the solver missed $(2,49^*7)$). Another solver did find all the ones @Michael found, and left a link to some code. http://oeis.org/A166749 seems to claim that the infinite family and the three sporadics are the only solutions, but doesn't give any hint of a proof.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Your conjecture has been proven by myself and Holo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paper [On finding all positive integers $a,b$ such that $b±a$ and $ab$ are palindromic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.08807), written by I and @TheSimpliFire, there is a full solution for (more general) question.

It was solved by restricting $a$ and then doing case by case analysis.

The only solutions are $(2,5\cdot 10^k-3)$, $(3,24)$ and $(9,9)$ for $k=0,1,2,3,\ldots$